# How to read Firefox log

Tags: firefox, tomcat, firefox-addon

I have a question about the log of Firefox Browser.

I am implement the automatic update feature of my Firefox extension, after following the tutorial at http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/automatic-firefox-extension-updates/ and getting some helps at post [Firefox extension automatic update feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466084/firefox-extension-automatic-update-feature), the update feature is still not working, but there are more information provided at the Firefox log. Can anyone please give me some advices or take some time to take a look at the log output. Thanks.

My development environment is

1. Firefox 5 on Ubuntu 11.04
2. Tomcat 6 server

The log output of a remove and re-install my extension is

```
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found
*** LOG addons.xpi: Opening database
*** LOG addons.repository: Requesting https://services.addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/api/1.5/search/guid:myextension%40mozilla.myextension.org?src=firefox&appOS=Linux&appVersion=5.0&tMain=23&tFirstPaint=1641&tSessionRestored=1042
*** LOG addons.xpi: Starting install of file:///home/me/browserplugindev/firefox/test/myextension.xpi
*** LOG addons.xpi: Addon myextension@mozilla.myextension.org will be installed as a packed xpi
*** LOG addons.xpi: Install of file:///home/me/browserplugindev/firefox/test/myextension.xpi completed.
NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi: Found updated manifest for myextension@mozilla.myextension.org in app-profile
*** LOG addons.xpi: Processing install of myextension@mozilla.myextension.org in app-profile
*** LOG addons.xpi: Opening database
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on myextension@mozilla.myextension.org installed in app-profile
*** LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
*** LOG addons.xpi: Updating add-on states
*** LOG addons.xpi: Writing add-ons list
```

Comment: That's merely the Firefox add-on manager log, not "Firefox log" (Firefox can create a number of different logs).

Comment: It makes sense since every single line starts with "*** LOG addons.xpi".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This log shows installation of an extension with ID `myextension@mozilla.myextension.org` from disk. Nothing special here - installation is scheduled, after a restart it is actually completed. Nothing about updates in that log (I guess that the installation was triggered manually).

Log entries referring to update checks rather than installation start with "addons.updates" and not "addons.xpi". When an update manifest is being checked you should see an entry "addons.updates: Requesting https://..." as well as additional entries in case of issues. Make sure that `extensions.logging.enabled` preference is set to `true` and that you actually trigger updates check - right-click your add-on in the add-on manager and choose "Find Updates" from the context menu.

Comment: Thanks a million Wladimir, It is working now. Answer accepted. I did do " - right-click your add-on in the add-on manager and choose "Find Updates" from the context menu." and that is why the update is not working. But, why the extension is updated by "manually" right click the extension and choose "Find Updates", not by finding its updates "automatically" when the Browser is started or restarted?

Comment: @user200340: Update checks happen delayed (10 minutes after browser start I think).